# How to join 2 tables on the same id but different date ranges?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using Presto SQL and trying to calculate the number of customers who login into a website day per segmented by country and customer_status? It takes 2 days to update the status from ‘new’ to ‘return’. Results should look like this:

```
date        country     status  total_count
2019-08-01  usa         new      1
                        return   null
            canada      new      1
                        return   1
```

```
table a : country of customers
login_date      id      country
2019-08-01      1       usa
2019-08-01      4       canada
2019-08-01      5       canada
2019-08-02      1       usa
2019-08-02      3       usa
2019-08-02      4       usa
2019-08-03      1       usa
2019-08-03      2       canada
2019-08-03      3       usa
2019-08-03      4       usa
2019-08-03      5       canada
```

…

```
table b : daily status of customers. 
**It takes 2 days to update the status from ‘new’ to ‘return’  
purchase_date       id      customer_status
2019-08-01      5           return
2019-08-02      4           new
2019-08-02      5           return
2019-08-03      1           return
2019-08-03      2           new
2019-08-03      3           return
2019-08-04      4           return
```

…

Any advice on how to join 2 tables that have different dates? I think the table should be join on the same date plus 2 days delay.

```
SELECT a.date,
a.country,
b.customer_status,
COUNT(id)
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON (a.id = b.id AND ‘how should I join on date that’s 2 days delay?’)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi, I'm using Presto SQL

Answer (score 1):

you need to this, `DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 2 DAY)`

```
SELECT a.date,
a.country,
b.customer_status,
COUNT(id)
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON (a.id = b.id AND a.login_date = DATE_ADD(b.purchase_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY))
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: `date_add` is non-standard SQL. Please mention for which DBMS product this works.

Comment: Thanks Mohideen! But it still doesn't work. I'm also using presto sql and already tried this:
````SELECT a.date,
a.country,
b.customer_status,
COUNT(id)
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON (a.id = b.id AND a.login_date = DATE_ADD(DAY, 2, b.purchase_date))
GROUP BY 1,2
````
https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: @mohideen-bin-mohammed @january28 DATE_ADD function's syntax is little wrong. It should be `DATE_ADD('DAY', 2, b.purchase_date)`